# Is there a way to pass reputation points when reposting an answer?

Tags: discussion, reposts

A scenario recently arose where a question was asked and an answer from a previous, similar question was completely relevant. I wondered, should I add a comment linking to the previous question or make an answer quoting the relevant answer and adding a link? Then I read [When the answer to a question exists on another site, what is the proper way to respond](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287/when-the-answer-to-a-question-exists-on-another-site-what-is-the-proper-way-to-r). Seems reasonable enough, but I feel like I should funnel any rep points I get for the answer back to the original answerer. I'm guessing this isn't possible, and maybe would be way to difficult or impractical to implement, but does anyone else think it would be a good idea?

Comment: If the question is different enough that it was not exact duplicate, then you had to do some work to provide the answer other than linking.  So do both: link with attribution and take credit for your work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you feel uncomfortable receiving rep from that post, you can either

- mark your answer as Community Wiki and receive no rep for up-votes, or
- use the bounty system to send those rep points to the OP of the answer

Remember that if you copy the text from the original answer, you're using content that has the cc-wiki license, so make sure you give the original author proper attribution.

Comment: Thanks. Both are good solutions.

Answer (score 6):

Better yet, if it's similar enough close the question as a duplicate of the original.

This is a little different from the question to which you linked in the sense that it's another answer on the site instead of a different site altogether.  Personally, I'd link to the other answer in a comment on the question.  That way you don't earn any rep on it and don't have to worry about funneling to the original answerer.  Chances are, then, that the original answer will get some votes which will, for all practical purposes, do the same thing as you suggest.